# Changing colours of items in FortuneItem in FortuneBar the flutter_fortune_wheel not possible?

Tags: flutter, styling, flutter-plugin

I have a flutter application and one of the things im using in it is the FortuneBar widget from the flutter_fortune_wheel plugin. The plugin supports direct customization of the FotuneBar using the "style: " property, but the same doesn't apply to the bar for some reason. The code with the widget is this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(113, 250, 202, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(60, 79, 118, 1),
            ],
            stops: [.30, .85],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 170,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: listManager.rewardsList.isNotEmpty && spinWheel
                  ? Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                      child: FortuneBar(
                        styleStrategy: const AlternatingStyleStrategy(),
                        selected: StreamController<int>.broadcast().stream,
                        items: [
                          for (var reward in listManager.rewardsList)
                            FortuneItem(
                              child: Text(reward),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ))
                  : const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Please enter 2 or more Rewards',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 4, 133),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            SpinButton(
                spinWheel: spinWheel,
                setSpinWheel: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    spinWheel = value;
                  });
                }),
            const SizedBox(height: 100),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I've tried countless methods using paddings, containers etc. Nothing really helps. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!